# The CateCollectionView outlet from the UIViewController to the UICollectionViewCell is invalid.

Tags: ios, swift3, uicollectionview

Illegal Configuration: The CateCollectionView outlet from the UIViewController to the UICollectionViewCell is invalid. Outlets cannot be connected to repeating content.

Answer (score 0):

Error was due to Outlet defined for UICollectivewView in another .swift or viewcontroller file.

After removing the CateCollectionView error gone.

[image]